# Java Byte Operation - Converting 3 Byte To Integer Data

Tags: java, int, hex, arrays

I have some byte-int operations. But I cant figure out the problem.

First of all I have a hex data and I am holding it as an integer

```
public static final int hexData = 0xDFC10A;
```

And I am converting it to byte array with this function:

```
public static byte[] hexToByteArray(int hexNum)
    {
        ArrayList<Byte> byteBuffer = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true)
        {
            byteBuffer.add(0, (byte) (hexNum % 256));
            hexNum = hexNum / 256;
            if (hexNum == 0) break;
        }

        byte[] data = new byte[byteBuffer.size()];
        for (int i=0;i<byteBuffer.size();i++){
            data[i] = byteBuffer.get(i).byteValue();
        }


        return data;
    }
```

And I want to convert 3 byte array to integer back again how can I do that?
Or you can also suggest other converting functions like hex-to-3-bytes-array and 3-bytes-to-int thank you again.

UPDATE

In c# someone use below function but not working in java

```
 public static int byte3ToInt(byte[] byte3){
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            res += res * 0xFF + byte3[i];
            if (byte3[i] < 0x7F)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: English is probably not your native language. Please don't say "I expect you to help me" unless you really mean it. It sounds rude and arrogant. Just so you know next time!

Comment: Thank you for correction, I don't mean it. I will try not to use again @NiklasR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the value:

```
(byte3[0] & 0xff) << 16 | (byte3[1] & 0xff) << 8 | (byte3[2] & 0xff)
```

This assumes, the byte array is 3 bytes long. If you need to convert also shorter arrays you can use a loop.

The conversion in the other direction (int to bytes) can be written with logical operations like this:

```
byte3[0] = (byte)(hexData >> 16);
byte3[1] = (byte)(hexData >> 8);
byte3[2] = (byte)(hexData);
```

Comment: For above example, I have tried and for 14663946 int value, return 704991

Comment: Right, the `hexToByteArray` method returns the bytes in the opposite order; see edit.

Comment: May I ask you something, can you review my first function and can you optimize like this?

Comment: Thank so much you again!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java NIO's ByteBuffer:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(hexNum).array();
```

And the other way round is possible too. Have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

As an example:

```
final byte[] array = new byte[] { 0x00, (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0xc1, 0x0a };//you need 4 bytes to get an integer (padding with a 0 byte)
final int x = ByteBuffer.wrap(array).getInt();
// x contains the int 0x00dfc10a
```

If you want to do it similar to the C# code:

```
public static int byte3ToInt(final byte[] byte3) {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
        res *= 256;
        if (byte3[i] < 0)
        {
            res += 256 + byte3[i]; //signed to unsigned conversion
        } else
        {
            res += byte3[i];
        }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: need to be 3 byte not 4

Comment: 3 bytes is not enough to hold a int, what are you going to do about the extra byte?

Comment: Furthermore, I can change it to 3 byte, I need to change it back to int and I will just use that kind of datas 0xDA10AB, 0xDFC10A..etc ..

Comment: @mismanc here you go. You might want to add some tests if you plan on using byte3ToInt in the future. Something like a check if it realy is a 3 byte array.

Answer (score -1):

to convert Integer to hex: `integer.toHexString()`

to convert hexString to Integer: `Integer.parseInt("FF", 16);`

Comment: He wants a byte[] not a String.

Comment: @Burkhard sting.getBytes(). Or it is always usefull to look to the interal implementation of method. It should be he most optimal

Comment: you are right I agree with you, But sometimes you just have to do it by thay way :p